# CakePHP comparing fields in multiple tables

Tags: mysql, cakephp, compare

I'm trying to compare fields in tables A, B, C, D to narrow down the id.

For example : I have id (1,2,3,4,5,6,9,10) in table A and want to compare the id with a_id in table B if they are equal then remove the id and so on.

Finally I can get few of them.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to compare them? Simply do a [deleteAll()](http://api.cakephp.org/2.5/class-Model.html#_deleteAll).

```
$this->Model->deleteAll(['a_id' => [1, 2, 3]]);
```

If you need to know if the A record exists just do a find('count') or exists() call on that model for the id and then call deleteAll() on the B model.

Comment: The reason i want to compare them is to show the id which doesn't exist in A,B,C,and D table.

Comment: Thank you I got a hint from your code to compare and delete them. Thank you !!